# Workaround for "Type parameter defaults can only reference previously declared type parameters."

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to type a class as follows:

```js
class State<TLinks extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> {
  async follow<TFollowResource = TLinks[TRel], TRel extends keyof TLinks>(rel: TRel): Promise<Resource<TFollowResource>> {
    // Ignore this line, just for testing
    return true as any;
  }

}
```

This throws the following 2 errors:

- Type parameter defaults can only reference previously declared type parameters.
- Required type parameters may not follow optional type parameters.

This is due to the 2 generic parameters on the `follow` function:

- `TFollowResource = TLinks[TRel]`
- `TRel extends keyof TLinks`

The obvious solution is to reverse the 2 generic arguments. Easy! Except, this is for an existing library and I'm adding the `TRel` argument. The reason I want it second, is because I don't want to break backwards compatibility for people of previous versions.

So my question is, is a workaround possible that lets me keep the original API but add this new generic parameter.

To make it easier to test, here's a more complete example:

```js
interface Resource<TKind> {

  get(): TKind;

}


/**
 * Broken =(
 */
class State<TLinks extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> {
  async follow<TFollowResource = TLinks[TRel], TRel extends keyof TLinks>(rel: TRel): Promise<Resource<TFollowResource>> {
    return true as any;
  }

}

type Author = {
  name: string;
}

(async() => {

  /**
   * These 2 tests show how it used to work
   * 
   * Note we're not passing a Links object
   */
  const s1_test1 = new State();
  /**
   * r1 should be Resource<Author>
   */
  const r1 = await s1_test1.follow<Author>('author');

  /**
   * r2 should be Resource<any>
   */
  const r2 = await s1_test1.follow('author');

  type Links = {
    author: Author
  }

  /**
   * In the second test we are passing a Links object
   */
  const s1_test2 = new State<Links>();
  /**
   * r3 should be Resource<Author>
   */
  const r3 = await s1_test2.follow('author');

});
```

And a [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&module=199#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-j9cgo0yq-V44mmWbLZhrRmKsV2AWi14S2WmD9-srJhDeaFJ1BeDmvFdPkx3fjkABJB5Ek2xLCuclDsWhKVy4yKuALpomDXahC6tuRs-GgdWsnRO0OhYVgqlMLrlniTByFAADMJpgrWfoBpgeyEBueYRgaX5drBcYJkmP5DiSI5ZuOhahlA04iKWQA)

The original class:

```js
class State {
  async follow<TFollowResource = any>(rel: string): Promise<Resource<TFollowResource>> {
    // Ignore this line, just for testing
    return true as any;
  }

}
```

The real interface from the open source library (in case this is helpful or gives more context): https://github.com/badgateway/ketting/blob/main/src/state/interface.ts

Comment: If you're adding the `TRel` argument, what was `TFollowResource`'s default before?

Comment: Why do you have an error on `await` in your playground link? Is that supposed to be part of a [mre] or is it an unrelated error you want people to ignore (and if so, could you fix it so that nobody has to actively ignore errors)?

Comment: ... Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wo8vgw) is what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, the error on await is weird, I changed the settings to ESM but I guess that information is not include in the playground link.

Comment: @jcalz looks like your playground approach is perfect for me. So would definitely appreciate the answer if you have more details to share, but I'm also analyzing it. Thank you!

Comment: The original value for `TFollowResource` was `any`. I've modified the question to show the original class.

Comment: So can you fix the `await` error with [this link](https://tsplay.dev/w25RrW) so we don't have to talk about it anymore?  I'll write up my answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz Sorr I got confused, but the error at your link is ideally something that also still works. The behavior I'm hoping for on that line is that users can still pass TResourceType. The purpose is that this is for a HATEOAS client and in the previous version users can specify what kind of resource they get when they follow.  (or get `any`)

Comment: It's a bit of a doozy but also happy to take that out to narrow the scope of the question, i can probably figure out how to make those last changes.

Comment: ☹️ My [most recent link](https://tsplay.dev/w25RrW) was meant to be asking you to remove the top-level `await` and just push that code down into a `async` function, so that the only errors remaining are the ones you are actually asking about. And my [original link](https://tsplay.dev/Wo8vgw) is the proposed fix, which I think does address all your issues.  I’m not sure how to communicate this more clearly.

Comment: @jcalz ah thanks for clarifying. Ill update it here.

Comment: @jcalz i updated the playground link, added another test case (to reflect the `any` behavior) and also updated the code shared here.

Comment: Okay I’ll take another look after I get some sleep and write up an answer if it still works with your updated version.

Comment: Thank you! I think I can probably figure it out based on what you sent though, so no problem if you don't feel like it! Appreciate the help.

Comment: I'd actually like to change the approach to overloads as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WKpxzw) because the previous version wouldn't catch an error where someone manually specifies the type argument but then passes in the *wrong* key.  If that works for you then I'll write up an explanation for this version.  Let me know.